# Can a contravariant functor be adjoint to a covariant one?

Tags: category-theory

I am a bit confused about the definition of adjoint functors, since everywhere the definitions found (see example wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) seem to not specify if we are working with covariant / contravariant / no-matter-the-kind-of functors.

I know that of course every contravariant functors is *essentially* covariant - is it enough to work in the opposite category? Sometimes this solution does not satisfy completely, especially when I have to do some explicit computation.

This is the case in an exercise I am trying to solve, where I have to prove that if $F$ is left-adjoint to $G$, then $F$ is right exact while $G$ left exact (I'll omit details because I know it is a well-known result).

I actually had no problem in doing this exercise, but I assumed that $F$ and $G$ were *covariant*. My proof seems still working in the case are both contravariant, but the case $F$ covariant + $G$ contravariant (as well as for the converse) is interesting. Here my proof seems to show that this case is not possibile, leading to the following conclusion:

> If $F$ and $G$ are two adjoint functors, they are both contravariant or they are both covariant.

Is this claim true, or am I missing some point?

Thank you.

Comment: How would you define adjointness in this case: You want a map from the composition to the identity functor. But the composition is no longer an covariant endofunctor, so what should the "identity" functor be?

Comment: Dear @TobiasKildetoft, do you mind to add some other details, please?
It seems to be the answer I need, but I don't manage to fill in all the details. Thank you!

Comment: Ahh, I didn't use quite the definition from the linked article I see. In that, you want an isomorphism between Hom-sets, which is fine. But that isomorphism must be natural, and if you try to write up that naturality, you will see that it becomes very strange when one of the functors is contravariant and the other is covariant.

Comment: In the definition of adjunction $F \dashv G$, you want (among other things) a natural transformation $G \circ F \to 1$. But $1$ is always covariant, whereas if (for example) $G$ is contravariant and $F$ covariant, then $G \circ F$ is contravariant...

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "works"?

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. For a moment everything seemed correct, so I wrote "Yes, it works" meaning "Yes, you are right".
Now actually there is something unclear.
 (1): "you will see that it becomes very strange when one of the functors is contravariant and the other is covariant": that's true, but...where is the contradiction?
(2): "you want (among other things) a natural transformation G∘F→1": why? Could you link me a reference/complete explanation, please?

Comment: Dear users, I think I solved. I read again more carefully the definition of being adjoint and actually the fact that $G$ and $F$ must be both covariant is requested by definition. The point is to notice the maps used in the commutativity of the diagrams exists iff $G$ and $F$ are covariant. By the way, of course thank you for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ and $G\colon\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ be (covariant) functors. Then $G$ is a left adjoint to $F$ if there exists a natural isomorphism
$$
\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(G(X),Y)
\xrightarrow{\sim}
\hom_{\mathcal{D}}(X,F(Y)).
$$
For contravariant functors the same definition applies once we make them covariant. There are two ways for doing so, let's examine them.

So, let $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ and $G\colon\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ be contravariant functors. We can get back to the previous situation by considering
$$\def\op{^{\mathrm{op}}}
F'\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}\op,\qquad
G'\colon\mathcal{D}\op\to\mathcal{C}
$$
and being $G'$ a left adjoint to $F'$ means there is a natural isomorphism
$$
\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(G'(X),Y)
\xrightarrow{\sim}
\hom_{\mathcal{D}\op}(X,F'(Y)).
$$
That's the same as saying there is a natural isomorphism
$$
\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(G(X),Y)
\xrightarrow{\sim}
\hom_{\mathcal{D}}(F(Y),X)
$$
(the functors are, in this case, *adjoint on the left*).

On the contrary, we could consider
$$
F''\colon\mathcal{C}\op\to\mathcal{D},\qquad
G''\colon\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}\op
$$
and, being $G''$ a left adjoint to $F''$ means there is a natural isomorphism
$$
\hom_{\mathcal{C}\op}(G''(X),Y)
\xrightarrow{\sim}
\hom_{\mathcal{D}}(X,F''(Y))
$$
which is the same as saying there is a natural isomorphism
$$
\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(Y,G(X))
\xrightarrow{\sim}
\hom_{\mathcal{D}}(X,F(Y))
$$
(the functors are adjoint to the right).

You can notice that, in case the categories are abelian, contravariant functors which are adjoint on the right are left exact; they are right exact in case they are adjoint on the left. I use the usual convention that the contravariant functor $F$ is called *left exact* if it transforms the exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ into the exact sequence $0\to F(C)\to F(B)\to F(A)$.

There is no way to sensibly pair up $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ and $G\colon\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ if one is covariant and the other one is contravariant, because making them both covariant messes up either the domain or the codomain.

You may try all positions of $F$ and $G$ in the hom sets, but you'll not be able to compose maps in order to define “being natural”, whereas this is obviously possible for pairs of covariant or contravariant functors.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm confused because adjointness is a property of pairs, with one functor left adjoint to the other, which is right adjoint to the first one, no? So, what is meant here by the saying "the functors are adjoint to the right", e.g. the last example. Do you just mean that the adjointness relationship is obscured because they are both written on the right side of the Hom sets?

In retrospect, I might have answered my own comment question.

Comment: @SamanthaY In the case of contravariant functors you can reduce them to covariant ones by applying composing them with $-^{\mathrm{op}}$, but it depends on where you place this which one becomes the right or left adjoint. There is no “canonical” choice.

Comment: Nevermind, it is, as I suspected, a terminology question that I had. Answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/88974/73967